# String of text To binary string To byte array To float and back Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary, byte

so i have a string of text and would like to convert it into a string containing the binary of the text,
then convert that binary string to an array of bytes holding the binary

then convert that array of bytes to a long

and then want to reverse the process

so far i have

```
public class Conversions
{
public Conversions()
{
}

public byte[] strToByteArray(String inPlainString)
{
    int byteValue;

    byte[] retArray = null;
    byte[] tempArray = inPlainString.getBytes();
    StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

    for (byte tempByte: tempArray)
    {
        byteValue = tempByte;

        for (int ii = 0; ii < 8; ii++) 
        {
            if((byteValue & 128) == 0)
            {
                binary.append(0);
            }
            else
            {
                binary.append(1);
            }

            byteValue = byteValue << 1;
        }

        binary.append(' ');
    }

    retArray = binary.toString().getBytes();

    return retArray;
}

public String byteArrayToStr(byte[] inArray)
{
    return inArray.toString();
}

public long getLongFromBytes(byte[] inByteArray, int inStart) 
{
    long retLong = 0;
    for (int ii=0; ii<8; ii++) 
    {
        byte value;

        if ((inStart+ii) < inByteArray.length) 
        {
            value = inByteArray[inStart+ii];
        } 
        else 
        {
            value = 0;
        }

        retLong = retLong <<8 | (value & 0xFFL);
    }
    return retLong;
}

public byte[] getBytesFromLong(long inLong) 
{
    byte[] retByteArray = new byte[8];

    for (int ii = 7; ii >= 0; ii --) 
    {
        retByteArray[ii] = (byte)(inLong & 0xFF);

        inLong = inLong >> 8;   
    }

    return retByteArray;
}

public byte[] combineByteArray(byte[] inArrOne, byte[] inArrTwo)
{
    byte[] retByteArray = new byte[inArrOne.length + inArrTwo.length];

    for (int ii = 0; ii < retByteArray.length; ii++) 
    {
        if (ii < inArrOne.length) 
        {
            retByteArray[ii] = inArrOne[ii];    
        }
        else
        {
            retByteArray[ii] = inArrTwo[ii - inArrOne.length];
        }
    }

    return retByteArray;
}
```

}

but when i attempt to test it as so

```
    Conversions convert = new Conversions();

    byte[] test = convert.strToByteArray("Hello there chaps");
            System.out.println("\n test1: " + test.toString() + "\n");

    long testL = convert.getLongFromBytes(test, 0);

    byte[] test2 = convert.getBytesFromLong(testL);
            System.out.println("\n test2: " + test2.toString() + "\n");

    String testStr = convert.byteArrayToStr(test2);
            System.out.println("\n test string: " + testStr + "\n");
```

i get the following

```
test1: [B@1bc4459


test2: [B@12b6651


test string: [B@12b6651
```

where am i going wrong?
/ can someone tell me how to go about converting text -> byte array of the binary -> long
long -> byte array of the binary -> the text

Comment: Calling toString on a byte[] will just print its reference. To create a string from a byte[] use new String(array)

Answer (score 0):

Calling toString on a byte[] will just print its reference. To create a string from a byte[] use:

```
byte[] array = // ..
String s = new String(array)
```